# How to open zip file and merge with existing folder?

Tags: macos, finder, monterey

I have a zipfile `config.zip` sibling to a directory `config`

I would like `config.zip` to be unzipped into `config` instead of into a new directory `config 2` (which is what double clicking in Finder does by default)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There's no option to do this natively. Even if you [expose the prefs for Archive Utility](https://www.howtogeek.com/284856/change-how-macos-handles-zip-files-with-these-hidden-preferences/), it's just not an option.

You'll need a 3rd party utility. There's [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com), mentioned in the linked article, which can do it - or a myriad other 3rd party utilities.

Comment: You're wrong about The Unarchiver, it does not allow to merge folders, always creates new ones.

Comment: @radzik - you have to set the prefs. It doesn't do it by default.

Answer (score 2):

Four easy steps in Finder (column view):

1. double click
2. select all files in `config 2`
3. drag them into `config`
4. decide whether to replace or keep (check box apply to all).

Other views add the step of opening `config 2`